# How can I specify a FileWatcher Modifier in Java9?

Tags: java, java-9

In Java 8, `java.nio.file.WatchEvent.Modifier` did not have any implementation, as its own Javadocs says: `This release does not define any standard modifiers.`

Java 9 seems to not have provided any either.

But in Java 8 I was still able to use the non-standard `com.sun.nio.file.SensitivityWatchEventModifier.HIGH` so that my file watcher would be more responsive (without this, it takes several seconds to get a notification, which is unacceptable).

In Java 9, this breaks as this is an internal API.

Is there any way to provide a modifier in Java 9 so that this works without using unsupported APIs? IF not, why the heck they thought it was a good idea to not provide any kind of configuration for this?

Comment: com.sun.nio.file is exported by the jdk.unsupported module. What issue are you running into?

Comment: As I said in the question, I would like to avoid using `unsupported` stuff.

Comment: There isn't a standard modifier for this. It's in the jdk.unsupport module as there suitable module for these extensions. If there were a native implementation of WatchService on macos then I assume the need for the polling based watcher would mostly go away.

Comment: Your last question makes a lot of sense, regardless of whether there is a way to get access to the nonstandard modifier or not. The other question would be, why on earth is this an interface that just encapsulates a name. Using strings as options, allowing the implementation to ignore unknown options, would make a lot more sense…

Comment: You shouldn't any --add-exports or --add-opens, it should just work becuase com.sun.nio.file is exported (see JEP 260). I assume the original question is from someone just wondering why this extension is exported by the jdk.unsupported module rather than another jdk.* module.